# Why is parent folder of jar also showing up in referenced libraries?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to find out why is Eclipse exhibiting this kind of behaviour when I add my own custom runnable jar as an external jar in one of my projects.

It does not do this for any of the other jars I downloaded, such as gson or Spring Boots, but only for the jars I created from my projects.

As you can see in the image below, both gson and my custom jar are in the same place but, when the gson jar was added, the downloads folder didn't show up in "Referenced Libraries". But, as soon as I added my custom jar, it shows up. Why is that so?

(I am adding these external jars via "configure buildpath" option)

[image]

Comment: Do you add the jar or the Directory to the build path?

Comment: i added the jar

Comment: Please post the contents of `.settigs/org.eclipse.wst.common.component` on your project's folder. And which version of Eclipse are you running?

Comment: eclipse neon is the version

Comment: where do i find this file which you have mentioned it doesnt appear in settings

Comment: Please show _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, tab _Libraries_. By the way, Eclipse Neon is pretty old, [please upgrade](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades).

Comment: From my tests, this odd behaviour appears only for executable jars.

Comment: @EugenCovaci yeah i guess so because i created a runnable jar.have you also observed this behaviour?

Comment: @howlger the tab shows only the the two jar file entries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to replicate this behaviour for executable jars. Actually, the problem is not with the executable nature, but with this line from manifest file:

```
Class-Path: .
```

Because of the above line, everything within the current folder is added to classpath.

As a solution, remove the line from the generated MANIFEST file within the generated jar file, then add the jar to classpath.

Comment: Just to make it clear i should remove the line from the manifest file of the generated jar or the project iam adding the jar to?ok the edit makes it clear.trying it out and gonna mark this as accepted once i see this works

Comment: @JayD Remove the line from the manifest file of the generated jar (the custom jar).

Comment: cheers!!! Eugene man this appears to resolve the observed behaviour. Can you please kindly upvote the question if it brought something new to your knowledge(if you didnt do so)..

Comment: @JayD I did upvote your question. I don't understand the reason behind downvotes .